# Maven: Cannot find symbol (classes) from parent pom

Tags: spring-boot, maven, parent-pom

I am not a maven expert and I am trying something new. I have created a framework which I want to use as parent project for all my microservices and which in turn containes all generic and abstract classes. I have declared packaging type pom in the framework pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>name</name>
    <description>description</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then I created a microservice(another maven project), where I declared my framework as parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>Be-ms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Be-ms</name>
    <description>Be-ms</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>col</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>col</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Unfortunately I'm gettin many 'cannot find symbol' at compile time... Why do I get these errors? Should not classes be found from parent pom?

[image: Generic service is not found]

Comment: have you checked all the parent dependencies get downloaded in your project? is your repository is having a parent jar?

Comment: Dear @Vaibs, thanks for getting in touch. I don't understand very well your question... there is not parent jar since the packaging is of type POM. Unfortunately dependencies in my parent pom have not been dowloader in my child project...

Comment: Maven first check on local then repository and then internet. This is way we configure our settings.XML. First make sure your parent jar is present in any one of the location and should be present before your child present.